# Images loading slowly (15+ seconds) in development?

Tags: asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-4

In my config/environment/development.rb file, I found that setting:

```
config.assets.debug = false  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
```

Considerably sped up my development server when using a large number of javascript and css files.

The only problem is that when loading images, the development server takes a long time to load each image.  The server output is as follows:

```
Started GET "/assets/shamcey/logo.png" for 10.0.2.2 at 2013-09-01 12:08:35 -0700


Started GET "/assets/shamcey/photos/thumb10.png" for 10.0.2.2 at 2013-09-01 12:08:36 -0700


Started GET "/assets/shamcey/leftpanelbg.png" for 10.0.2.2 at 2013-09-01 12:08:36 -0700


Started GET "/assets/shamcey/icons/message.png" for 10.0.2.2 at 2013-09-01 12:08:37 -0700


Started GET "/assets/shamcey/icons/users.png" for 10.0.2.2 at 2013-09-01 12:08:37 -0700


Started GET "/assets/shamcey/icons/bar.png" for 10.0.2.2 at 2013-09-01 12:08:38 -0700


Started GET "/assets/shamcey/droparrow.png" for 10.0.2.2 at 2013-09-01 12:08:38 -0700


Started GET "/assets/shamcey/bg1.png" for 10.0.2.2 at 2013-09-01 12:08:38 -0700


Started GET "/assets/shamcey/bcarrow.png" for 10.0.2.2 at 2013-09-01 12:08:39 -0700


Started GET "/assets/shamcey/bcarrow.png" for 10.0.2.2 at 2013-09-01 12:08:39 -0700


Started GET "/assets/shamcey/glyphicons-halflings.png" for 10.0.2.2 at 2013-09-01 12:08:39 -0700


Started GET "/assets/shamcey/icons/search.png" for 10.0.2.2 at 2013-09-01 12:08:40 -0700


Started GET "/assets/shamcey/icons/icon-event.png" for 10.0.2.2 at 2013-09-01 12:08:40 -0700


Started GET "/assets/shamcey/icons/icon-cart.png" for 10.0.2.2 at 2013-09-01 12:08:40 -0700


Started GET "/assets/shamcey/icons/icon-archive.png" for 10.0.2.2 at 2013-09-01 12:08:41 -0700


Started GET "/assets/shamcey/icons/icon-help.png" for 10.0.2.2 at 2013-09-01 12:08:41 -0700


Started GET "/assets/shamcey/icons/icon-images.png" for 10.0.2.2 at 2013-09-01 12:08:42 -0700


Started GET "/assets/shamcey/glyphicons-halflings-white.png" for 10.0.2.2 at 2013-09-01 12:08:42 -0700


Started GET "/assets/shamcey/calarrow.png" for 10.0.2.2 at 2013-09-01 12:08:42 -0700
```

Is there anyway to speed up the loading of images in development mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves the problem.

```
config.cache_classes = true
```